# set option in a custom select in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, electron

The html, css and js part are in this link [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)

The problem:

This is an electron desktop app.

I want to retrieve some data from database and display in the window.

I do not know how to set the custom-select without clicking in the gui.

I need to set the option from JavaScript itself.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do u mean that you need to feed your dropdown menu through a database or you need to use js to set a default selection from dropdown dynamically ? i can't recognize your question aims,

Comment: I need to set an option using the data I retreived from database. I retreived the data sucessfully. I cannot figure out a way to set the option to the select. @BurhamB.Soliman

Comment: you need to set an event for each selection, so when user select an item you want it to show up a result if that what you means so you need to add `onchange` event to your selection tag, example : `<select id="selectionchange" onchange="changefunc()">` and add a function using javascript to do your job, 
`<script>
function changefunc() {
  var selection = document.getElementById("selectionchange").value;
  // use anyaction you need with the variable named 'selection'
}
</script>`

Comment: I tried using it. But it clases with the existing js in the  and the select is not rendered at all. Pls help. @BurhamB.Soliman

Comment: All necessary information should be in the question. See [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to programmatically add your options to an existing selector. Consider the following:

```html
<select id="mySelector"></select>
```

Say you have the above somewhere in your electron app template. Once you receive the data from the database, create each option dynamically and append to this selector:

```js
const data = [ { name: 'Option1', value: 'value1' }, { name: 'Option2', value: 'value2' } ]; // assuming the data is an array of objects
const sel = document.getElementById('mySelector');
data.forEach(opt => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('value', opt.value);
    option.innerHTML = opt.name;
    sel.appendChild(option);
});
```

The output generated should be as follows:

```html
<select id="mySelector">
    <option value="value1">Option1</option>
    <option value="value2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps you to understand how to dynamically add content to your page using JavaScript.

**Edit**

To select an option, simply add the `selected` attribute to the option:

```js
option.setAttribute('selected', true);
```

**Edit 2**

After taking a brief look at your code (specifically js/expense.js), I can see you are actually creating a div element and trying to emulate the feature of an option element. In that case, setting `selected` attribute will not work. Since you are creating this div yourself, there are many ways you can mark any of the option div as selected. For instance, you can listen for `click` event on each of the option div and then assign a data property to mark it as selected. Based on your code:

```js
a.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-selected', 'true'));
```

The above snippet assumes that `a` is a div element you created using `document.createElement('div')`. The snippet adds a `click` handler and on click simply adds a data attribute on the option. Now you should add other checks to make sure that you remove the `data-selected` attribute from other options in case the user changes the option later.

Finally, to lookup the option selected, you can try the following:

```js
const selected = document.querySelector("div[data-selected='true']");
```

Note: The value for `data-selected` is a string and not boolean. So you can add any value that evaluates to `true` to indicate selection.

Comment: No I don't want to dynamically add a list of options. I just need to display a option as selected one. I tried option.setAttribute('selected', true); It is not working. Pls can you help me?  @Abrar

Comment: Please share your code. It was not clear enough in your question and I apologize for the extra details. I have used setAttribute before and it has worked without issue so, without looking at your code I can't comment further

Comment: This is the github link. Pls take a look. https://github.com/sankarsubramaniankvs/wallet-electron

Comment: your code throws an error "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." change sel.appendChild(opt); to sel.appendChild(option); at second code block

Comment: @Ivandez I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

as per what i understand that you need to make selection action, so i added to you the action needed inside the if selected statement

```
if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You selected: " + y[i].innerHTML;
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
```

check the snippet

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        sl = s.length;
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            yl = y.length;
            for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");

  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You selected: " + y[i].innerHTML;
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="selectone" onchange="selectfunc()">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: No I have like a window to retrieve a data and display it. The user already selected the data and it is store as a record in database. Now I need to display it in a new window (kinda like browsing through database in gui). After i retreive data, I need to set it.  @Burham

Comment: you can change the action to what exactly you want, i'm just giving you the hint how to get the result, so you need to change the output statement to your own
here is wt i used to show up the result, you can replace 
        `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You selected: " + y[i].innerHTML;`
 with your code using the same variable `y[i].innerHTML`